# checkbox using v-for in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, bootstrap-5

Now I'm having trouble selecting CheckBox.
By me looping in the DataTable and adding a Checkbox to it.
And I have stored it as an Array. What I want is when I select the left tick, I remove the right tick. And if you tick the right side, remove the tick on the left side.

```
<tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in PersonalDocument" :key="item.doc_id">
        <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
        <td>{{ item.doc_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.doc_name }}</td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-check-input"
            v-model="temp_doc_file"
            :value="{
              doc_id: item.doc_id,
              doc_status: 0,
            }"
          />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            class="form-check-input"
            v-model="temp_doc_file"
            :value="{
              doc_id: item.doc_id,
              doc_status: 1,
            }"
          />
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: where is your logic for doing so? there's nothing in what you posted that would even attempt to do what you want - not sure you want `v-model="temp_doc_file"` for every single checkbox in that v-for either

Answer (score 0):

If You want to use checkboxes as a Radio then you need to use in both checkboxes @change="YourMethod()" then define a functionality.
template

```
 <script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    const PersonalDocument = ref([
    {doc_id : 1, doc_name: 'heehhe'},
    {doc_id : 2, doc_name: 'heerrrrrhhe'},
    ])
    
    const temp_doc_file = ref({})
    const check = ref({})
    
    const msg = ref('Hello World!')
    function YourMethod(index, side) {
          const leftCheckboxId = 'left' + index;
          const rightCheckboxId = 'right' + index;
          const leftCheckbox = document.getElementById(leftCheckboxId);
          const rightCheckbox = document.getElementById(rightCheckboxId);
          if (side === 'left') {
            if (leftCheckbox && rightCheckbox) {
              if (leftCheckbox.checked) {
                temp_doc_file.value = {
                  doc_id: PersonalDocument.value[index].doc_id,
                  doc_status: 0,
                };
                rightCheckbox.checked = false;
              }
            }
          } else if (side === 'right') { 
              if (leftCheckbox && rightCheckbox) {
                if (rightCheckbox.checked) {
                  temp_doc_file.value = {
                    doc_id: PersonalDocument.value[index].doc_id,
                    doc_status: 1,
                  };
                  leftCheckbox.checked = false;
                }
            }
          } 
          
             console.log('test', temp_doc_file.value)
        }

    </script>
    
    <template>
     <tr v-for="(item, index) in PersonalDocument" :key="item.doc_id">
            <th scope="row">{{ index + 1 }}</th>
            <td>{{ item.doc_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.doc_name }}</td>
      <td>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                :id='"left"+index'
                class="form-check-input"
               
               @change="YourMethod(index, 'left')"
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                :id='"right"+index'
                class="form-check-input"
                
                @change="YourMethod(index, 'right')"
              />
            </td>
            </tr>
    </template>
```